# Gradle under Docker - Could not open cp_proj remapped class cache

Tags: jenkins, gradle, docker, gradlew

I've installed Jenkins 2.6 as a docker container on a Windows 2012 Server machine.

I have created a project that checks out a project from git.

I've configured a build step that does a build using gradle wrapper 2.13

The gradle command fails with:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'test'.
> Could not open cp_proj remapped class cache for 6f7e45oinduki44jplv0c4r9s (/var/jenkins_home/.gradle/caches/2.13/scrip
ts-remapped/build_4xwqfk0ckitkb3fdwi5uf1f5e/6f7e45oinduki44jplv0c4r9s/cp_proj57408229).
   > java.io.FileNotFoundException: /var/jenkins_home/.gradle/caches/2.13/scripts-remapped/build_4xwqfk0ckitkb3fdwi5uf1f
5e/6f7e45oinduki44jplv0c4r9s/cp_proj57408229/classes/build_4xwqfk0ckitkb3fdwi5uf1f5e$_run_closure1$_closure3$_closure5.c
lass (Operation not permitted)

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED
```

I've tried remoting into the container and running the gradle command manually but get the same error.

I found an article on the internet that recommended deleting the lock files: cache.properties.lock

This has not helped.

I've also tried restarting the container but this has not helped either.

Comment: I found there is a file in that path called:  /var/jenkins_home/.gradle/caches/2.13/scripts-remapped/build_4xwqfk0ckitkb3fdwi5uf1f5e/6f7e45oinduki44jplv0c4r9s/cp_proj57408229/classes/build_4xwqfk0ckitkb3fdwi5uf1f5e\$_run_closure1\$_closure2.class

Comment: Tried building directly with gradle from the command line:
/var/jenkins_home/.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-2.13-bin/4xs
gxlfjcxvrea7akf941nvc7/gradle-2.13/bin/gradle buildImage

Still the same issue

Comment: Don't get this problem when running a Jenkins docker container in a CentOS 7 host.

Comment: did you found the solution? It seems that I have the same problem

Comment: No I didn't find a solution for Windows so I used a Linux host instead

Comment: Another solution would be to install Spring Boot App plugin under Eclipse and run project with it. Seems to work fine. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem which at least for me was because of two reasons:

1. My java home system variable was pointing for jdk7 instead of jdk8
2. The proxy was blocking jCentral.

Solution:

1. For first cause the solution is pretty simple. I just pointed the JAVA_HOME for having java 8 version
2. In the user home directory(which for me was c:/users/)/.gradle i created a file named gradle.properties in which I put the next settings:

   systemProp.http.proxyHost=..

   systemProp.http.proxyPort=..

   systemProp.http.proxyUser=..

   systemProp.http.proxyPassword=..

   systemProp.**https**.proxyHost=..

   systemProp.**https**.proxyPort=..

   systemProp.**https**.proxyUser=..

   systemProp.**https**.proxyPassword=..

Hope this will be useful for someone else in the future.

Comment: My java home system variable was pointing for jdk7 instead of jdk8 -- This resolved my issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I searched for HOURS and tried numerous things but the only one that worked for me was going to "C:\Users\YOUR-USERNAME.gradle" and deleting the "cache" folder. Or rename it "cache-BACKUP" if you want to be cautious. Fixed everything for me.